# android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" works on Application level but not at the activity level. Any clue?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, statusbar, android-theme

I need to make one of my activities called `MyNoStatusBarActivity.java` a full-screen activity.

I have added in the Manifest :

```
<activity
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:name=".MyNoStatusBarActivity"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation">
    ...
</activity>
```

And in the `onCreate` of my activity :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Doing all this just hides the TITLE bar and not the STATUS bar.

Also if I use the manifest theme on the application level instead of my activity, it works but for all activities of my app which is not what I want. I want the no status bar only for one particular activity.

Help will be really appreciated. Thnx!

P.S : I am ok is this behavior is no longer available in Honeycomb/ICS. I need this just for 2.2 and 2.3

**EDIT**

Tried all the suggestions mentioned in other solutions in SO but no success yet. Theme works when applied to the application level but not on the activity level.

I am using HTC WildFire-S, android ver 2.3.5

Answer (score 29):

In your manifest xml, at application level put this:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
</application>
```

and in the activity that you want to make full screen put this:

```
<activity

     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
     ...
</activity>
```

Remove all the setWindowsFeature or setFlag methods in onCreate.

Comment: I believe so. I used to test this on android 2.2

Answer (score 6):

I think you just need to take the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` out of the mainfest, stick with code only call, it's always worked for me. Which test device are you using?

Also make sure these calls come *before* you call to `setContentView(R.layout.xxx)` like this

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.xxx);
```

Check all of your code for `android:theme` declarations, ie manifest and individual layouts xml files. as it sounds like declaring it at app level is working (as it's overriding any subsequent theme declarations) but there is something overriding your activity level request.

Try searching your whole project for "android:theme" and remove anything that you're not 100% sure you need, test it that way

Comment: Doesnt work. Only Title goes off but status bar remains. I am using HTC WildFire-S, android ver 2.3.5

Comment: Infact it appears like the top part of the activity is going below the status bar. Status bar seems to have some kind of high z-index and hides a part of my fullscreen activity !

Comment: are you sure there are no other xml theme declarations in your project?

Comment: have you also checked the individual layout files? (the ones located in res/layout)

Answer (score 3):

I put this in my activity:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```

And in my manifest I don't modify, this is mine, without modifications:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

In my activty xml:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your problem

just change in your manifest @android:style... for @style/..

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    ...
</application>
```