# Navigation bar appears briefly when switching activites

Tags: java, android, nexus-7

I am currently writing an Android app with a completely full screen experience (the system bar and navigation bar are not displayed until the user swipes down) for a Nexus 7 tablet.

For some reason, when I switch activities, the navigation bar reappears briefly.

To create the full screen effect, I set to the system UI visibility to predetermined options in each activity's `onResume()`, register a UI change listener, and register a window focus listener.

**UI Options**

```
private View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

private int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
```

**Setting the System UI Visibilility in onResume()**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

}
```

**Setting the System UI Visibility When the UI Changes**

```
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (
            new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int pVisibility) {

                    if ((pVisibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
                    }

                }

});
```

**Setting the System UI Visibility When the Window Has Focus**

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean pHasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(pHasFocus);

    if(pHasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }

}
```

All of the things above are done in each activity of the application to ensure that the
navigation bar and status bar are hidden when a keyboard goes away, an activity is resumed,
etc.

But, I still have the problem of the navigation bar appearing briefly when I switch between
activities.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem and eliminate some unnecessary code snippets that I had in my app.

Making an app full screen -- including hiding the navigation and status bar -- involved quite a few parts:

**Set the app theme in the android manifest to "Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"**

(Done in AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

**Create global variables for the window decor view and UI options**

(Done on the programming side of all activities)

```
private View decorView;
private int uiOptions;
```

NOTE: Do not define until onCreate()

**Define decorView and uiOptions and call a function to create a UI change listener in onCreate()**

(Done on the programming side of all activities)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

    uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    createUiChangeListener();

}
```

**Set the system UI visibility in onResume()**

(Done on the programming side of all activities)

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

}
```

**Code for the createUiChangeListener() function called from onCreate()**

(Done on the programming side of all activities)

```
private void createUiChangeListener() {

    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (
            new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int pVisibility) {

                    if ((pVisibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
                    }

                }

            });

}
```

Comment: This causes heap size to increase, have you noticed this? As reference please refer to my question, I used the same approach as yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492441/why-does-heap-size-keep-increasing

Answer (score 3):

You need to use themes for application and activity styling as explained here: [android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" works on Application level but not at the activity level. Any clue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086371/androidtheme-androidstyle-theme-notitlebar-fullscreen-works-on-application). Those are the ones applied when creating the view, instead of removing them after creating in onResume, like you do.

Basically, you need to set a theme for the application that won't have a title bar/action bar (if you already have a theme, have it extend this one):

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</application>
```

Similarly for every activity:

```
<activity

     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
     ...
</activity>
```

And in activity's onCreate:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```