# Why does heap size keep increasing?

Tags: android, heap-memory, heap-dump, rippledrawable

I have an application that has a lot of ripple effects and animations.

I tried going back and forth multiple screens, and also spam clicking buttons.

I noticed that the heap size continuously goes up even though some screens have already been closed.

When I checked the heap dump, the class with the highest Retained heap was the `android.graphics.Bitmap` class and points to all of the buttons I clicked that has a Ripple Effect.

The Ripple Effects on the buttons are just simple ripples which uses `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` as the background. But it goes up by 0.3mb or 0.5mb on every click of the buttons with ripples.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a MemoryLeak of some kind. It's almost impossible to tell where is the problem without analise the code. I recommend some tests.

You could try the [Leak Canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) library. The lib can "watch" specifics objects and narrow the search for the leak.