# How to remove title bar in android api 22 and api 25?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-developer-api

I am using android studio 2.2.3. How can i remove title bar from my application?
I am tried by putting

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

in **AndroidManifest.xml** file but it doesn't worked.

Here is screenshot my project
[My Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHG3D.png)

My **Style.xml** file code is

```
<style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> </style>
```

What should have to change in style.xml file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086371/androidtheme-androidstyle-theme-notitlebar-fullscreen-works-on-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this style in Style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        - <!--  All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here.
  -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Comment: Thanks brother it works..

Is There any different method you know apart from this?

Answer (score 1):

**Programmatic way**

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
       setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your line this way

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: It also won't works...!! `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`